# How to make Alexa/Google home read a whole text file using nodeJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, alexa-skills-kit, google-home

I have the following code which helps me extract the text from a text_file line by line:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');
const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream('./rooms.txt')
});
// Each new line emits an event - every time the stream receives \r, \n, or \r\n
rl.on('line', (line) => {
    console.log(line);
});
rl.on('close', () => {
    console.log('Done reading file');
});
```

This code works. However I have been unable to use the line variable outside of its scope in order to pass it to the function that would actually prompt Alexa to say those line.
I have tried using a callback function but it did not work.
Any suggestions as to how make use of the "line" variable outside of the scope of

```
rl.on('line', (line) => {
    console.log(line);
});
```

**Grateful!**

Comment: ` I have tried using a callback function but it did not work` show that please.

Comment: @JonasW. Since, I am relatively new to JavaScript, the way I implemented the callback function was really messed-up. So, if you could suggest a way to do it, it would be great :)

Comment: Show your code! Otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: You can use a global variable and store whatever you need in there. And then later use it. Although this is not encouraged.

Comment: @NikhilWagh but the global variable value remains unchanged oustside of the scope of :rl.on('line', (line) => {
    console.log(line);
});   so it's like I did nothing